# Is it possible to POST associations using "finder" URIs in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest

I would like to POST to create entities using associations that specify "finder" URIs rather than "identity" URIs. Is this possible?

POST this:

```
{
    "username": "gonzo",
    "role": "http://x.com/roles/nameequals?name=admin"
}
```

NOT this:

```
{
    "username": "gonzo",
    "role": "http://x.com/roles/1"
}
```

When I try this I get an error from Spring REST "failed to convert from type java.lang.String to type java.lang.Long for value 'name'" which I guess means it's not supported. I was hoping that there was some way of enabling this feature. Though that's probably wishful thinking.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

No, that's not supported. The URI needs to identify an item resource as we extract the backend ID from the URI directly to invoke `findOne(…)` on the repository.